# add a parameter to a selector in effect

Tags: angular, store, ngrx

I have the following

```
  createMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.CreateMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.CreateMissionRequest),
    withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(MissionsStoreSelectors.getById(), {id : action.payload.routeId}))
    switchMap((action) =>
      this.dataService.createMission(action.payload.mission).pipe(
        map(response => new featureActions.CreateMissionSuccess({response, mission : action.payload.mission})),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('ERROR.HTTP.GENERIC'), this.translate.instant('BUTTON.OK'), {duration: 2500});
          return of(new featureActions.CreateMissionFailed({error}));
        }),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

the problem is, in the withLatestFrom I want to use a parameter in the selector, coming from the action. How do I achieve that ?

```
    withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(MissionsStoreSelectors.getById(), {id : action.payload.routeId}))
    switchMap((action, valueFromLatest) =>
```

EDIT : I TRIED

```
  @Effect()
  createMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.CreateMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.AssignMissionRequest),
    withLatestFrom((action) => this.store$.select(MissionsStoreSelectors.getById(), {id : action.payload.routeId})),
    switchMap((mission, action) =>
      this.dataService.createMission(action.payload.mission).pipe(
        map(response => new featureActions.CreateMissionSuccess({response, mission : action.payload.mission})),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('ERROR.HTTP.GENERIC'), this.translate.instant('BUTTON.OK'), {duration: 2500});
          return of(new featureActions.CreateMissionFailed({error}));
        }),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

but i have type error on action.payload (action became a number) doesn't seem to work

Comment: arent the selectors jsut methods you define yourself ? then nothing can stop you from adding a filter to them

Comment: I know, the problem is I don't know how to access the action from outside the switchmap to go in the withLatestFrom

Comment: try doing something like this : `(action)=>withLatestFrom(this.store$.select(MissionsStoreSelectors.getById(), {id : action.payload.routeId}))` with a debugger and see what you get

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `switchMap` and a `combineLatest` to achieve that, but I haven't seen in your code where you want to use the result of the selector (the data coming from the selector). I assumed that the original action (`CreateMissionRequest`) has two attributes in its payload: `routeId` and `mission`. But it doesn't make any sense because you use the selector and never use it's result again. But you can get the overall idea looking at the technique below and do whatever you want to.

**UPDATED**

```js
createMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.CreateMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.CreateMissionRequest),
    // This is where you use the switchMap
    switchMap((action) =>
        // combineLatest here makes it possible to pass forward the results
        // from the selector and the original action if you need
        combineLatest([ 
          this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.getById(), {id : action.payload.routeId}),take(1)),
          of(action.payload.routeId),
        ])),
    switchMap(([mission,routeId]) =>
      this.dataService.createMission(mission).pipe(
        map(response => new featureActions.CreateMissionSuccess({response, mission})),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('ERROR.HTTP.GENERIC'), this.translate.instant('BUTTON.OK'), {duration: 2500});
          return of(new featureActions.CreateMissionFailed({error}));
        }),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

In fact, if you just need to convert an observable to another, the `switchMap` can do the job for you, there's no need for `combineLatest`:

```js
createMission$ = this.actions$.pipe(
    ofType<featureActions.CreateMissionRequest>(featureActions.ActionTypes.CreateMissionRequest),
    switchMap((action) =>  
        this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.getById(), {id : action.payload.routeId}),take(1))),
    switchMap((mission) =>
      this.dataService.createMission(mission).pipe(
        map(response => new featureActions.CreateMissionSuccess({response, mission})),
        catchError((error: HttpErrorResponse) => {
          this.snackBar.open(this.translate.instant('ERROR.HTTP.GENERIC'), this.translate.instant('BUTTON.OK'), {duration: 2500});
          return of(new featureActions.CreateMissionFailed({error}));
        }),
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Comment: I am not passing the mission in parameter, just the mission ID, and I want to sent that mission present on the store to a server.

Comment: Also, it says combineLatest is deprecated, but will try to implement this, thanks

Comment: You must import `combineLatest` from `rxjs` instead of from `rxjs/operators`. It's not deprecated, but you have to pass an array as arguments, even if you have just one argument. I've forgotten the latter.

Comment: I tried your exemple, but with the double switchMap, everytime my mission is saved, the selector fire angain, and I get stuck in an infinite loop.

Comment: That's weird. The `switchMap` following the `store$.pipe(...)` should cancel the selector subscription. Anyway, I added a `take(1)` in the `store$.pipe(...)`. If it's still firing, it's likely something else in another part of the code.

Comment: Pipe output of combineLatest to Take operator like below to avoid infinite loop. Inner take(1) will be repetitive if combining more than 1 selectors.
combineLatest([ 
          this.store$.pipe(select(MissionsStoreSelectors.getById(), {id : action.payload.routeId})),
          of(action.payload.routeId),
        ]).pipe(take(1))